# How do I toggle the display of <div> in Rails 3?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, toggle

I have a  within a form that contains other fields for the form.  I would like the User to be able to toggle whether they see it or not.

I would like them to be able to press a button/link which would make that div appears or disappear.  *Ideally* I could have some simple javascript effect, such slide in or fade-in.

Here is my _form:

```
  1 <%= form_for @message do |f| %>
  2   <%= f.error_messages %>
  3   <p>
  4     <%= f.label :subject %><br />
  5     <%= f.text_field :subject %>
  6   </p>
  7   <p>
  8     <%= f.label :body %><br />
  9     <%= f.text_area :body %>
 10   </p>
 11   <p>
 12   <div id = "contact_form">
 13      <%= form_for @contact do |fc| %>
 14         <p>
 15           <%= fc.label :first_name %><br />
 16           <%= fc.text_field :first_name %>
 17         </p>
 18         <p>
 19           <%= fc.label :last_name %><br />
 20           <%= fc.text_field :last_name %>
 21         </p>
 22 
 23      <% end %>
 24   </div>
 25   </p>
 26   <p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to use the .css rule of the jQuery javascript library:

http://api.jquery.com/css/
(See the example about a quarter down: *To change the color of any paragraph to red on mouseover event.*)

So using this you'd use this javascript on clicking the button/link:

```
$('div#contact_form').css('display', 'none');
```

Comment: hehe, two "the easiest way" answers

Comment: how do I use that javascript snippet when clicking on the link itself?  Is this for clicking on the actual div?  thanks...

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to add a link somewhere to call a script like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'visible';
}
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="show('contact_form'); return false;">show sub-form</a>
```

Comment: ...of course you could also just do the script portion inline within the `onclick` property.